# Animate scroll to ID on page load

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

Im tring to animate the scroll to a particular ID on page load. I have done lots of research and came across this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#title1').height() }, 1000);
```

but this seems to start from the ID and animate to the top of the page?

The HTML (which is half way down the page) is simply:

```
<h2 id="title1">Title here</h2>
```

Comment: This isn't much of an answer, but I highly recommend Ariel Flesler's "scrollTo" plugin; it has a lot of features for panning about a page, and a few extensions to the plugin for common cases (for instance, you might find his "LocalScroll" plugin useful for scrolling to a link's href if it's on the same page).

You can get the plugin here: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You are only scrolling the height of your element. [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns the coordinates of an element relative to the document, and `top` param will give you the element's distance in pixels along the y-axis:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#title1').offset().top }, 1000);
```

And you can also add a delay to it:

```
$("html, body").delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: $('#title1').offset().top }, 2000);
```

Comment: What is it about automatic scrolling that makes me go "WOW COOL!!"?  Maybe it's the simplicity of your solution.

Comment: I needed to scroll an element into view on page load, but had two issues: a) using "html,body" gave two callbacks (one for each matched element).
b) It depends on browser which of body or html works. So I made a gist which you can adapt to use in your project to ensure scroll-into-view works on "any" browser and that you will only get one callback when animation ends.
https://gist.github.com/netsi1964/4ddffe1ae14e05220d25

Comment: This isn't really correct. You really should consider the current scroll position of body or element that we are trying to `scroll`. With that in mind you would add the current scroll position of the `body` to the `offset().top` position of the element we want in view, The resulting sum is the value we want to scroll to.`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('html, body').scrollTop() + $('#title1').offset().top) }, 1000);`

Comment: @magreenberg have you tried this out? If current scroll position is anything above value 0 then what you're suggesting might not work. Let's say that scrollable container is 1000 pixels tall and the current scroll position is at 1000. Let's say the element you're scrolling to sits in the vertical center at 500. I think that what you're suggesting would tell it to scroll to 1500, right?

Comment: @BumbleB2na `.offset().top` would give you a negative number in this instance. And this really only works for `body` and `html` since `offset().top` is going to give you the document top offset, not the intended scrolling parent.

Comment: @magreenberg Thank you, you saved me so much grief. I had a div that is not 100% height with `overflow-y: scroll` set. This works perfect as long as you also subtract the distance between the top of the page and the div.

Comment: And if you set `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` style, you should give 0 to duration: `$("html, body").delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: $('#title1').offset().top }, 0);
`

Answer (score 23):

Pure javascript solution with [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function:

```js
el = document.getElementById('title1')
el.scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
```

```html
<h2 id="title1">Some title</h2>
```

P.S. 'smooth' parameter now works from Chrome 61 as **julien_c** mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Works now (from Chrome 61)

Comment: Be sure to check browser compatibility.As of 10/2018 IE (11),Edge and Safari support "scrollIntoView" but not the "smooth" option.

Comment: Pure JS ftw. Thanks for that snippet! Smooth as double buttery cream

Answer (score 5):

**Deprecation Notice:** The `jQuery.browser` property was removed in jQuery 1.9. Visit the docs for more details: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
$(jQuery.browser.webkit ? "body": "html").animate({ scrollTop: $('#title1').offset().top }, 1000);
```

Source: [jQuery Animate Body Scroll For All Browsers](https://harmstyler.me/posts/2013/jquery-animate-body-for-all-browsers/)

Comment: jQuery.browser() was removed in jQuery 1.9 so this isn't a great option anymore

Answer (score 3):

There is a jquery plugin for this. It scrolls document to a specific element, so that it would be perfectly in the middle of viewport. It also supports animation easings so that the scroll effect would look super smooth. Check [this link](http://plugins.jquery.com/animatedscrolljs/).

In your case the code is

```
$("#title1").animatedScroll({easing: "easeOutExpo"});
```

Comment: "It also supports animation easings so that the scroll effect would look super smooth" Unfortunately, that does not hold true. If the computer is slow for some reason it just keeps jumping without actually moving properly.

Comment: Smooth scrolling requires a lot pixels to be calculated. Sure a slow "computer" (more GPU) cannot do this but due to lacking enough ALUs. So generally he is right. And really easy scrolling lib.

Answer (score 1):

try with following code. make elements with class name **page-scroll** and keep id name to `href` of corresponding links

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

for simple Scroll, use following style

height: 200px;
        overflow: scroll;

and use this style class which div or section you want to show scroll