# Make scrolling div 'smooth scroll' on desktop and mobile? NOT TO ANCHOR TAG

Tags: jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

The site can be viewed [here](http://www.tomsalta.com/?page_id=8).

I want the scroll box to scroll smoothly on desktop and mobile devices. Not smooth scrolling to an anchor, just a normal scroll. I tried a CSS3 transition and also a jQuery plugin that didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/jquery-animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/jquery-animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load)

Comment: You're talking about the copy box, correct? Did you try the default scroll bar for that instead of something custom?

Comment: I'm talking about the scrolling div on the right with the text in it. Yes it didn't smooth scroll before those custom bars were implemented either.