# JQuery detect if an element with particular id is visible after page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollview

I want to create the navigation as it is shown on page http://kiskolabs.com/

I've already created sticky menu however the problem begins with marking active element in menu.

**The question is:**

How can I detect if page is scrolled to particular id?

Let's say I have some headers like.

```
<h1 id="whatisit">What is it</h1>
<h1 id="desc">Description</h1>
<h1 id="faq">FAQ</h1>
```

and menu

```
<nav>
  <a href="#whatisit">What is it</a>
  <a href="#desc">Description</a>
  <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
</nav>
```

I want highlight menu (add class or whatever) when page scrolls to this element.

I've found already how to scroll element to particular ID in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/jquery-animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load) but I don't know how to detect on what id the is now. The size of page is dynamic and may change during content. So absolute solution what I thought of is bad.

What I got so far for scrolling:

```
$("nav a").click(function (){
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

I've also found [this solution](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about)  but maybe is there better way to achieve it?

**Edit**

This question is not duplicate of the question suggested by moderator. Moreover, that question does not have the accepted answer. My problem is a bit more advanced.

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate? Simply stating it will not convince anyone. Add details to your question that demonstrate the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a lot of trying and finding solutions in Internet I've solved my problem.

I've used **waypoints plugin** which appeared very easy to use. The plugin can be downloaded [here](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).

**The html code of menu:**

```
        <nav>
            <a href="#whatisit" class="scrollable">....</a>
            <a href="#howworks"  class="scrollable">....</a>
            <a href="#whydata" class="scrollable" >....</a>
            <a href="#spec"  class="scrollable">...</a>
        </nav>
```

and **html code of headers where page is to be scrolled:**

```
<h2 class="scrollable" id="whatisit">...</h2>
<h2 class="scrollable" id="spec">...</h2>
```

**Jquery code**  to make page scroll on particular element with #id the same as `a href` attribute.

```
$("nav a.scrollable").click(function (){
    var elementClickedHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(elementClickedHref).offset().top-100
                 }, 2000);  
    return false;
});
```

To change color of element which is currently active after scrolling I've used **waypoint** plugin. The code below finds `h2` which is scrollable and get it's id. Then finds which links that are scrollable too has `href` same as id of `a` element and adds active class to this id and remove active class from inactive elements.

```
$('h2.scrollable').waypoint(function() {
    var idToCheck = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    $('a.scrollable').removeClass('active');
    $('a.scrollable[href="'+idToCheck+'"]').addClass('active');
}, {
    offset: '100%'
});
```

It works perfectly as I wanted. I hope this solution will help someone who will face such problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use animate callback function:

```
$("nav a").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.href).offset().top
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).addclass('scrolled').siblings('h1').removeClass('scrolled');
    });
});
```

Comment: what if person does not use click on `nav a` and scroll the page with scrollbar?

Comment: Well, you could still code this logic yourself but i'll suggest to handle all case to use then a plugin, maybe the plugin linked in your question.  You are correct, i misread your question