# jump to id with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm rebuilding a website based on previous guy. Here is the source code, it used id to jump when clicked.

```
<a href="#faq01">Cancel or Modify an Order</a>
```

click and jump to

```
<a name="faq01" id="faq01"></a><strong>Cancel or Modify an Order</strong></p>
<p> Please kindly contact our customer service to cancel or modify your order. However, once your order has been processed and ...</p>
```

Is there a simple way to make this jump smoothly? The category is extremely big but in the same format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate scroll to ID on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/jquery-animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load)

Comment: Here is the reference http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, hope it will help

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```