# How to change jquery one page scroll navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using the jquery plugin one page scroll (http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

I want to keep the stock navigation that gets added on the right side, but I also have a fixed navbar were I want the links to navigate to the different divs on the index.html file.

I was thinking to give each div a specific id, but how I would I get the navigation to work with the smooth scrolling?

Comment: You may consider to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead. The navigation you try to create sounds like a menu for me, which is linked to the sections. This is very simple to accomplish with fullPage.js

Answer (score 0):

[Animate scroll to ID on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/jquery-animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load)

Here it is, with this piece of code, you can scroll on a page smoothly.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#objectToScroll').offset().top }, 1000);
```

Comment: Needs to work with the plugin I posted. It takes care of hiding and showing each individual div.

Answer (score 0):

Just use classes, not id's, then you can apply the same class to multiple elements. Hence, your horiz nav can have the same links as the sidebar dots/right navigation.