# scroll window on click jquery?

Tags: jquery

To Be precise I need to scroll the window to the top of a `div` on click of a button.

I tried this:

```
$(".red").animate({"scrollTop": $(".red").scrollTop()},1000);
```

But didn't worked

Check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gu8gx1ad/3/

Comment: Check console for errors.

Comment: But I have the function `sc` what is wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate scroll to ID on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 2):

You have to scroll `html,body` wrt your element like

```
$("html,body").animate({"scrollTop": $(".red").offset().top},1000);
```

Snippet,

```js
function sc(w) {
  var cls = '';
  switch (w) {
    case 0:
      cls = '.green';
      break;
    case 1:
      cls = '.blue';
      break;
    case 2:
      cls = '.red';
      break;
  }
  cls && $("html,body").animate({
    "scrollTop": $(cls).offset().top
  }, 1000);

}
```

```css
.green,
.red,
.blue {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#green" style="color:green;" onclick="sc(0)">green</a>
<a href="#blue" style="color:blue;" onclick="sc(1)">blue</a>
<a href="#red" style="color:red;" onclick="sc(2)">red</a>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick for you. But it only works after the corresponding sections have their ID names not class names :

```
<a href="#green" style="color:green;" onclick="sc(0)">green</a>
<a href="#blue" style="color:blue;" onclick="sc(1)">blue</a>
<a href="#red" style="color:red;" onclick="sc(2)">red</a>
<div id="green" ></div>
<div id="blue" ></div>
<div id="red" ></div>



    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to use JQuery to do this. All you need to do is give the dive an id and reference that in your link as per below.

```
<a href="www.domain.com/#red">GoToRed</a>

<div id="red">
    div content
</div>
```

Comment: While this is simpler, it doesn't animate the page scrolling down as the jQuery version does. That may be a requirement the OP has. Also, just FYI the downvote isn't mine.