# How to browse down to bring element to the center of the screen?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `Reply` button at the middle of the page after a variable length text. When the button is clicked a reply form appears:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#reply").click(function(){
     $("#replyform").toggle(1000);    
  });
 });
```

The problem is that when the form appears, it often falls outside of visible area. 
My question is how to scroll down automatically to `replyform`, so that the form appears at the center of the browser, hence becomes clearly visible?

Comment: Check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682515/4090870

Comment: Great. This  exactly does what I meant: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#replyform').offset().top }, 1000);`