# How Can I Use Animate to Go To Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {        
    window.location.replace("#goToDiv");        
});
```

My code is in here. When i click .myClass button, the user goes to #goToDiv. But I want the animation for this. For example, it can go like transitive passing. How can I use animation for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate scroll to ID on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = this.hash;
  var $target = $(target);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 900, 'swing', function() {
    window.location.hash = target;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .animate() function with scrollTop.

Use this:

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {        
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#goToDiv").offset().top
    }, 1200);      
});
```